# In android studio, it can't find button id on activitymain.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, button

[image: button id on layoutxml]

[image: Error in MainActivity.xml]

As you can see, I write an id to button in layoutactivity but it can't find on mainactivity. How can I fix this. I searched but I can't find. By the way I'm using the  Android Studio version 4.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: solution]

Firstly, you should open Gradle Scripts and then Build Gradle Module file.At the top of the page, you can see plugins. You should add "id 'kotlin-android-extensions'" as in the image.